# Reading iOS drive with VB.NET

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have a VS2015 / VB.Net app which reads folders/files on connected removable drives and I'd like to expand the app functionality to also read files from a virtual iOS folder (eg: connected iPhone). iOS drives are not mapped to a drive letter so my app cannot recognize it. I have been searching extensively for ways to do this and concluded it cannot be done natively with just VB.Net. It appears I need a hook of some sort that my app calls which can read the iPhone photo files. I came across "UWP" in my web research and have a couple questions before I even think of committing to it: 1) Can UWP in fact read iPhone folders connected to a Win 10 desktop? 2) Is UWP integrated with Visual Studio 2017? 3) Is VS2017 backward compatible with VS2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 Can UWP in fact read iPhone folders connected to a Win 10 desktop?

UWP support [Media Transfer Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.portable), And you could use uwp app to access IOS [`StorageDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.portable.storagedevice)

```
var folder = StorageDevice.FromId(deviceInformationId);
```

And you could also create AutoPlay UWP app for auto playing image, audio, video in IOS device. For more you could refer [**Auto-launching with AutoPlay**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/auto-launching-with-autoplay).

> 2) Is UWP integrated with Visual Studio 2017?

In general, Visual Studio 2017 contain UWP project template by default, and you could also check it manually.
[image]

> 3 Is VS2017 backward compatible with VS2015?

VS2017 is backward compatible. You could open the solution that create with VS2015 via VS2017 if you has install lower UWP SDK version.